2021 LSOA shapefile for London
I am trying to download a shapefile (polygon) for the 2021 Census Lower layer Super Output Areas (LSOA) for London. I came across this webpage,but whenever I select the shapefile, or geopackage or geojson the geometry is empty (i.e., there are no polygons).
I can easily find LSOA for 2011 but not for 2021. Can someone help me to find the shapefile (or geopackage, or geojson) for the year 2021?

That page only includes the names and codes for the zones, to be honest I can't think why anyone would want just those. You want the boundaries for the zones which can be found at https://www.data.gov.uk/dataset/d5505463-73e9-4030-9c77-f6596dca1ef7/lower-layer-super-output-areas-december-2021-boundaries-ew-bfe-v9
